# Compression Sleeves/Socks for Achilles Tendonitis

Tags: running, injury, compression

This year I've been running much more than years past, and I have my first trail half marathon (with 2500' of elevation gain) coming up in 1 week. 3 weeks ago I was running a hilly training run and my Achilles got really tight and painful.  I took it easy for a week, but it keeps flaring up on training runs. I've found lots of ice, and Ibuprofen seems to help some, as well as rolling my calves seems to help... and i've resorted to cross training only these last 2 weeks to give it some rest.

I'm to stubborn to not run my race, and so my question(s) is(are):

- Will wearing compression sleeves or socks help with this issue?
- Are some brands better for the Achilles tendon than others?
- Are socks better than sleeves?
- Is there any chance wearing compression socks/sleeves would make the issue worse?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they will help the achilles problem.

My advice:

You don't need to stop running necessarily, but you don't want it to get any worse. Start with active stretching (running drills), start running slowly and work up to the pace you are aiming for. You could also try heating your achilles up before you go run as well. Afterwards check out [PNF Stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNF_stretching), or basic static stretching, foam roller.

Go see a physical therapist, start working on stretching out the achilles as well as the calf. If the physical therapist has it and is trained to use it, have him/her use kinesio tape on your achilles. If you cannot afford a PT, check out Rock Tape, you can find it from $15 to $20 depending on the website. The stuff works.

Comment: Kinesio tape is still somewhat controversial and unproven. It's certainly been a fad for a bit, but studies have failed to show help/improvement. But, if it works for you, great! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if a Calf sleeve is going to solve your problem, it certainly won't hurt.

Here is what I suggest:

Stretch before you run
Ice after and often during the day
Take Ibuprofen to reduce the swelling
Avoid hills if you can: The strain on your achilles is greater as you ascend a hill
Slow down, the less strain you put on your achilles the less likely you will damage it.
If it is persistently sore - STOP RUNNING

The most important part is REST

http://www.runnersworld.com/injury-prevention-recovery/inside-doctors-office-keep-achilles-tendinitis-away

I didn't stop running and I have had some scar tissue that is annoying and sore. If you rest and let it heal now, you will save yourself weeks of recovery in the future.